# Make UITextField Cursor Blink Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to make some of my UITextField's blue cursor start to blink programmatically, as if they were just pressed by the user.

I know this [great post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) by Matt Gallagher on how to simulate touch events for test purposes, but it won't work for production purposes.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

`[theTextField becomeFirstResponder]` should do the job.